# ExtJS form field -- set multiple values

Tags: extjs

I am using the Ext.form.field.Tag component. If I copy paste a string of values in the correct format, all the values are selected and everything works perfectly. However, if the values arent pasted correctly i.e spaces before and/or after comma, no comma at end of string etc some of the values dont sync.

The issue I am facing is if the string is in the incorrect format, I can correct it by removing whitespaces before/after the commas, but I never get the chance to do so.

For example, if the pasted string is:

```
"1,2,3, 4, 5, 6, 7,8,9,10,"
```

only the values with no space between the comma before and after it will sync with the drop down list. So

```
1,2,3,8,9, and 10
```

will sync, but the rest will get ignored.

Anyone have any suggestions on what the best way to handle this would be?

I need something like a "beforechange" event because "change" is fired only after those values have been synced and at that point the ignored values have been lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the field (this) in the change event contains a property called "lastMutatedValue" which equals the pasted string and is exactly what I needed.

```
change:function(fld_){
  var str = fld_.getValue();
  if(fld_.lastMutatedValue){
    //concat current values with copy pasted values
    str = str + "," + fld_.lastMutatedValue.replace(/\s*,\s*/g, ',');    //removes any white spaces before/after commas
  }
  fld_.setValue(str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try 'focus' event? It should be triggered before 'change' event.

Comment: "focus" is fired before I even paste the values in.